# How to convert Location Area Code to the address?

Tags: java, android, location, gsm, telephonymanager

I want to get the tower locations, for this I am using TelephonyManager and I am getting the Location area code but this I want to convert in string to show the location.

```
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation)telephonyManager.getCellLocation();

    int cellid= cellLocation.getCid();
    int celllac = cellLocation.getLac();


    Log.d("CellLocation", cellLocation.toString());
    Log.d("GSM CELL ID",  String.valueOf(cellid));
    Log.d("GSM Location Code", String.valueOf(celllac));
```

Here is the code, Where I am getting location area code, How can I convert it to string?

Please help thank you..

Comment: You can use Geocoder, it can convert location to address.

Answer (score 2):

The LAC code is just an operator identifier for the location of an area ovf coverage - there is no algorithm etc to convert from it to a GPS location or street address.

There are databases that exist which contain a mapping cell ids to locations - for example, this is one of the best known:

- http://www.opencellid.org

You need to remember these are essentially just look up services so if the info is missing or wrong in their database you will not get the correct answer - i.e. it is not based on any algorithmic mapping from the LAC.

There is also a Google MAP's API which will allow you pass the mobile base station information and receive a GPS location in response:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro

This is a web service - you send a HTTPS POST message and get a response back. An example JSON for the request and response, based on the above link at the time of writing, make it fairly clear how it is used:

Request JSON:

```js
{
  "homeMobileCountryCode": 310,
  "homeMobileNetworkCode": 410,
  "radioType": "gsm",
  "carrier": "Vodafone",
  "considerIp": "true",
  "cellTowers": [
    {
      "cellId": 42,
      "locationAreaCode": 415,
      "mobileCountryCode": 310,
      "mobileNetworkCode": 410,
      "age": 0,
      "signalStrength": -60,
      "timingAdvance": 15
    }
  ]
}
```

Response JSON:

```js
{
  "location": {
    "lat": 51.0,
    "lng": -0.1
  },
  "accuracy": 1200.4
}
```

You do need an API key to use the service - see the link for the details.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution this I tried from postman and I am getting the lattitude and longitude from cell id and location area code. But as I am trying to get response in an app I am getting 400 response code, 400 response code shows as invalid api key as per developer document, but the same api key works in postman. What can be the issue? can you help please?

Comment: I would check quickly that you are definitely using HTTPS rather than HTTP and also maybe try to capture the traffic to make sure the app is not modifying the URL and the key somehow. If the problem persists, then I would say open a new specific question about it to get it more visibility.